# What does Section-unaligned hotplug range mean?

Tags: boot, virtualbox

When my Ubuntu VM starts up I get these messages:

```
Section-unaligned hotplug range: start 0x1000000000, size 0x91c00000
```

[image]

What do these messages mean, should I be worried, and, if so, how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

It shows because some hotpluged memory is not aligned to page so it will not be used. It's added in [this patch](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1766314) to the kernel. The solution is probably VM dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Disable dynamic memory usage on your VM, and set fix memory size (for example: Hyper-V) and restart your server.